# OpenShift Online 3 with filezilla?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

How can we connect filezilla with **OpenShift Online 3** created account. Where we can get ftp details or from where we can add ssh public key.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift 3 doesn't provide any way of interacting with it via ftp or ssh. It isn't like a traditional web hosting service. Would suggest you read through the free book:

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

to get an idea of how OpenShift 3 is used.

As to manually transferring files to a container running your application, to for example populate a persistent volume which has been mounted into it, see https://learn.openshift.com and the scenario about transferring files.

Be aware that unless you copy files into a mounted persistent volume, those files will be lost on a restart, as the filesystem of the container is otherwise ephemeral.

Comment: And this one? https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/

Comment: That blog post is for OpenShift 2, not OpenShift 3. Not the same.

Comment: FTP is really useful, practical and in some way "traditional": why suppress it?

Comment: OpenShift is not like your traditional web hosting service. Providing FTP access doesn't really make much sense in way that it does for old way of doing things.

Comment: It's ok for me, but of course, if I have to host my project and I have not any time to learn new things, I will probably choose more traditional ways (moreover, other cloud services at the moment offer FTP). Don't get me wrong, I liked OpenShift a lot when I tested version 2  :-)